# Samsung galaxy S4 translucent status bar won't work as expected

Tags: android

I'm using

```
getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION );
```

to get a translucent status bar with lollipop and later version, it works as expected on any emulator but from my galaxy S4 (with android 5.0.1) my status bar is fully transparent (no black background with opacity).

Is this related to my device? has someone already experience this on some devices?

Thx!